# sails blueprint view iterates over hidden properties of empty object

Tags: sails.js

I am new to sails, and trying to output a basic list coming from the find action from the blueprints.
Using an example view from the docs:

```
<ul>
  <% _.each(data, function (project) { %>
    <li><%= project.name %></li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

and checking the value of matchingRecords in the node-inspector returns [] (which i expected).
The view however lists 2 items with value undefined, see image below:

[image: empty list should be empty :p]

If I add data into the model, it iterates over the json returned by the blueprint char by char. I must be doing something wrong, but I am kind of stumped. I originally used Jade, and thought maybe there is something wonky with the template adapter, but as I said, ejs gives me a very similar result.
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks like in the view, the available global variable `data` is a string, as returned by `typeof data`

Comment: show us how you are passing data to the view

Comment: @yBrodsky I am using the blueprint as is, so I am not passing anything. I am relying on the return of `res.ok(matchingRecords);` in the `find` action

Comment: I found out just now that `data` is a string in the view, so doing `each project in eval(data)` (adding the eval), works, I do not think this is intended though.

Comment: Yea, I dont think either. Try to overwrite the blueprint with a method in the controller and pass the data manually and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @yBrodsky I have the same issue with a very simple controller and the same view:

`all: function(req, res) {
    matchingRecords = [{
      id: 11,
      name: "test"
    }];
      return res.ok(matchingRecords);
  }`

Comment: I wonder if maybe it could be something with my version of node.

Comment: Have you tried passing the value to the view using res.view(data)?

Comment: @yBrodsky, yes, using `res.view` works, though the blueprint scaffold is kind of useless, if that is the issue. I opened a bug at the sails repo to investigate, maybe something will come out of it.
Thanks for your time !

Comment: I think that blueprints are meant to be used for REST Apis, not with views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in sails at the moment of writing.

An issue has been opened on Github https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3932